# Push Notification Android working alright previous, stops abruptly

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Integrated Push Notification in an app via gcm.jar in my app which was working alright till 8 hours back. I know as that was the time I received the last one.

Here's is my GCM intent service:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_registered));
        ServerUtilities.register(context, registrationId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
            ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
        } else {
            // This callback results from the call to unregister made on
            // ServerUtilities when the registration to the server failed.
            Log.i(TAG, "Ignoring unregister callback");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");

        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message, url);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message,"");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        // log message
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
                errorId));
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */

    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message, String url) {
        int icon = R.drawable.app_icon;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.e(TAG, message);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Intent notificationIntent;
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(url)){
            notificationIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        }else{
            notificationIntent= new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
        }
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

}
```

And with the appropriate permissions, in manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.packageappname" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Had referred (implemented exactly that actually): http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Right now I'm not receiving the notifications that are being pushed. I checked: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Do I have to mandatorily implement the new GCM to make it work or is there some problem with my intent service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use C2DM in one of my old apps and just tested to push and it's working here. 
Sometimes behind wifi home router or any rauter the push is not going through, maybe it's just my router but anyway restart router. It's not a bad idea to migrate, I did that, took me a week to learn and get stuff right. Did you see the [migrate page](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html)

Comment: thanks , migrate how?is there any other useful link except the google one (i have mentioned in the question)  and still is there any reason it should not work for now??

Comment: Since you know C2DM you could pick any GCM tutorial and start from scratch on a Tutorial project. Just google it. It's should work for you since it's working for me. Maybe the darn regId is not sent to your server

Comment: To start with, did you see the [migrate page](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html)

Comment: i am getting a success response from server for push notification sent

Comment: I remember this behaviour, I have a few devices and sometimes the C2DM work on one but not on the other. It's usually because the device is jammed somehow, memory issue, network issue. restart it